# QML ColumnLayout misplacing Items

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.3

Window {
    id: root
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Redundant Coding")

    RowLayout{

        ColumnLayout{

            Layout.leftMargin: root.width / 16
            Layout.rightMargin: root.width / 16

            Text {
                id: selectedAlgorithmText
                text: "Wybrany algorytm:"
                font.pixelSize: 16
            }

            Text {
                id: algorithmText
                text: qsTr("Hamming")
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }

            Slider {
                id: slider
                snapMode: RangeSlider.SnapOnRelease
                stepSize: 1
                to: 2
                value: 0
            }

            Button {
                id: confirmButton
                text: qsTr("Zatwierdź")
            }


            Button {
                id: exitButton
                text: qsTr("Wyjście")
            }

        }

        ColumnLayout{

            Image {
                id: image
                width: 300
                height: 300
                source: "../assets/test.png"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }

            Text {
                id: descriptionText
                width: 300
                height: 300
                text: qsTr("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
                font.pixelSize: 24

                wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I would want 2 ColumnLayout next to each other, each occupying some percentage of width.
Elements in both columnlayout are misplaced, what i mean is, instead of being placed at the top of the screen, which logically should happen, they are misplaced near the middle, for some unknown reason to me.

This is how it looks:

[image]

The image and the text are placed near the middle, not at the top, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Anchor your `RowLayout`, e.g. `RowLayout { anchors.fill: parent }`
2. For proportional `ColumnLayout`, e.g. 20% - 80% split, use something like

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    ColumnLayout { Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.preferredWidth: 200 }
    ColumnLayout { Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.preferredWidth: 800 }
}
```

3. For sizing items within layouts, use `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight` not `width` and `height`

Altogether:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            Layout.leftMargin: width / 16
            Layout.rightMargin: width / 16
            
            Text {
                id: selectedAlgorithmText
                text: "Wybrany algorytm:"
                font.pixelSize: 16
            }
            
            Text {
                id: algorithmText
                text: qsTr("Hamming")
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }
            
            Slider {
                id: slider
                snapMode: RangeSlider.SnapOnRelease
                stepSize: 1
                to: 2
                value: 0
            }
            
            Button {
                id: confirmButton
                text: qsTr("Zatwierdź")
            }
            
            
            Button {
                id: exitButton
                text: qsTr("Wyjście")
            }
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 800
            
            Frame {
                id: image
                Layout.preferredWidth: 300
                Layout.preferredHeight: 300
                Image {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    source: "../assets/test.png"
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                }
            }
            
            Text {
                id: descriptionText
                Layout.preferredWidth: 300
                Layout.preferredHeight: 300
                text: qsTr("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
                font.pixelSize: 24
                
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)